# Circular dependencies when doing constructor injection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm building a metrics application with two models: Metric and Measurement. A metric has many measurements and a measurement belongs to a metric.

These models are persisted to, and fetched from the database using two mappers: MetricMapper and MeasurementMapper. These classes are instantiated and declare methods like #find and #save.

To make my code base as modular as possible I use constructor injection to supply these mappers with their dependencies:

```
db = ...
metric_mapper = MetricMapper.new(db: db)
```

The MeasurementMapper#find method can optionally load the measurement's metric at the same time:

```
measurement = measurement_mapper.find("some_id", load_metric: true)
measurement.metric #=> <Metric>
```

To be able to do this the MeasurementMapper is instantiated with a MetricMapper:

```
db = ...
metric_mapper = MetricMapper.new(db: db)
measurement_mapper = MeasurementMapper.new(db: db,
                                           metric_mapper: metric_mapper)
```

This is all fine and works great. The issues with this design patterns starts to show when I want the MetricMapper#find method to be able to load the metric's associated measurements at the same time.

```
metric = metric_mapper.find("some_id", load_measurements: true)
metric.measurements #=> [<Measurement>, <Measurement>, ...]
```

To do this the MetricMapper needs to be instantiated with a MeasurementMapper. The thing is that to instantiate the MeasurementMapper we need a MetricMapper which means that we now have a circular dependency.

How can I change my design to remove this circular dependency without making one of the classes aware of the other?

Comment: Have you looked into [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org)? This kind of thing is directly handled by RoR. Basically it doesn't seem necessary to have separate Mapper classes. Ultimately the one-to-many relationship is modeled by a single `metric_id` column in the Measurements table, right? If you don't use RoR, then write your associative methods in each Measurement and Metric class. It is natural that these two classes are aware of each other.

Comment: The idea behind having separate Mapper classes is to make the models themselves agnostic of how they are persisted. One of the gains of doing this is that I can experiment with different persistence models without affecting the computational logic that is encapsulated inside the actual models. The models know about each other but not about how they are persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I know a guy that solves it in a awesome way! https://github.com/calleerlandsson/q/blob/master/lib/q/metric_mapper.rb#L8